# What happens if locally manifold is seen as an Euclidean space?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topology

I have been trying to understand the definition of a manifold and I have found out that the most common definition can be paraphrased as:

*A manifold is a space that has a complex "topology" globally but "locally" can be considered (dealt with as) Euclidean .*

So, what is the advantage (if any) if locally a manifold can be considered as an Euclidean space?

Comment: You're basically asking: Why are manifolds nice things to deal with? That's (1) incredibly broad (2) a mathematics question.

Comment: I am rather asking what can be done locally that can not be done globally in the case of a manifold? What are the advantages physically? If you still insist that it is a mathematical question, I can move it to math.stackexchange.

Comment: I think that, in order to appropriately answer that, it's best to read a textbook on the matter. A pure mathematics book like Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" can be super interesting, but so can a more physically oriented book like Isham's "Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists". In any case, the answer is extremely long and multi-faceted.

Comment: I was thinking maybe that calculations would be easier locally if it were an Euclidean space? I am just assuming. @Danu

Comment: In a *VERY* over-simplified sense, the main idea is that it allows us to carry over most notions that we know from $\mathbb{R}^n$ almost unchanged. This includes, most notably, calculus.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Quote taken from exactly where?

Comment: Few answers to questions I saw here on S.E. (this is well-known definition) @Qmechanic

Comment: @Danu I was thinking now, so this is why we say that maps on a manifold take portions of that manifold to coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward advantage is that manifolds are a useful way to talk about things that locally look like Euclidean space.

Historically, the notion was developed so that you could do things like talk about surfaces (e.g. spheres) in a way that only made reference to the surface itself; that is without reference to the three-dimensional space they're embedded in. A main application of this was that the process discovering what and how to translate between the ambient geometry and the geometry of the surface itself allowed mathematicians to distinguish between intrinsic and extrinsic properties; e.g. a cylinder is a flat surface, despite the fact it looks curved in three dimensions.

A more modern application is that we know from centuries of experience that the shape of the universe looks locally like Euclidean space, and thus the language of manifolds is a convenient one to develop general relativity in.

Comment: Thank you for the historic overview, but if you can add anything that tells what is the advantage? I can read that you may mean that it could be easier to visualize. Is it?
If you look at my conversation with Danu, he said there "the main idea is that it allows us to carry over most notions that we know from Rn almost unchanged. This includes, most notably, calculus".